# how to echo array data from pinterest oauth api php

Tags: php, oauth, pinterest

I am trying to get user profile from pinterest using oauth api.
code for user data :

```
$me = $pinterest->users->me(array(
'fields' => 'username,first_name,last_name,image[large]'
));
```

and echo result by :

```
echo $me;
```

the output is as follow :

```
{"id":"195414208739840616","username":"rajivsharma033","first_name":"Rajiv","last_name":"Sharma","bio":null,"created_at":null,"counts":null,"image":{"large":{"url":"https:\/\/s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com\/avatars\/rajivsharma033_1459712414_280.jpg","width":280,"height":280}}}
```

Now i want to echo this result as

```
id="195414208739840616"
username="rajivsharma033"
first_name="Rajiv"
```

and so on...
please help me.

Comment: echo is not working without for loop. It is displaying syntax error (Adobe Dreamweaver)

Comment: @Anant code is working fine...can you help me in displaying image url from code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are getting `json` data so you need to use `json_decode()`:-

```
   <?php
    $me = '{"id":"195414208739840616","username":"rajivsharma033","first_name":"Rajiv","last_name":"Sharma","bio":null,"created_at":null,"counts":null,"image":{"large":{"url":"https:\/\/s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com\/avatars\/rajivsharma033_1459712414_280.jpg","width":280,"height":280}}}';

    $array_data = json_decode($me); 
    echo "<pre/>";print_r($array_data);

    foreach ($array_data as $key=>$value){

        if($key == 'image'){
            echo $key. " url is=" . $value->large->url .'<br/>';
        }else{

            echo $key. "=" . $value .'<br/>';
        }
    }
```

Comment: please check the code and change the text according to your wish. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would solve it by using two times `foreach`:

```
$a = json_decode($me);
 foreach ($a as $key=>$value){
echo $key.'="'.$value.'"<br/>';
}
foreach ($a['image']['large'] as $key=>value){
 echo 'image-large-'$key.'="'.$value.'"<br/>';
}
```

Alternatively, you can do this recursive:

```
function echojson($string=''){
 $a = json_decode($me);
 foreach ($a as $key=>$value){
  if (is_array($value)) echojson($string.'-'.$key);
  else
  echo $string.$key.'="'.$value.'"<br/>';
 }
}
```

Comment: this is not displaying (echo) image URL ??

Comment: @DeepakSingh thats right. I forgot this in my code. For this special case, i added an additional loop to my answer